# Draggable blocks with gravity (div with a link)

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, gravity

I need to do a section on a website which contains some draggable "bubbles" and which has a gravity effect and bouncing.

This is the reference website https://www.goldinteractive.ch/news, do even know any plugin or any hint to make it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a better understanding of how it works [here](https://burakkanber.com/blog/modeling-physics-javascript-gravity-and-drag/), and if you still need examples make sure to check our the examples on codepen.io by just searching for gravity.